# Adding additional conditions to find_by_id in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using Rails 3.2.11 on a Mac

I have this statement that works fine:

`object= Object.find_by_id(params[:id])`

I'm trying to add a condition to that statement so I did this:

```
object = Object.where("id = :id AND level <= :level",{:id => params[:id], :level =>     current_user.level})
```

Will there be any risk in this method? Any alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

There's no risk presented by this statement, provided that ActiveRecord continues to uphold the contract of sanitizing input. An alternative would be a scope, but that's really just doing the same thing in a different syntax.

One thing you could do is [set a default scope](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Default/ClassMethods/default_scope) that defines the `level` restriction, then you could just do a standard `find_by_id`. But if that's undesirable, just use the syntax properly:

```
Object.where(id: params[:id], level: current_user.level)
```

Comment: it works. however, when I use it some of the methods become undefined. is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There is no risk but the way it is defined is not easy to understand.

The simple statement will work:

```
object = Object.where("id = ? AND level <= ?",{params[:id],   current_user.level})
```

Answer (score 0):

as long as you let rails handle the sanitizing of your values, you'll have no issues.  what i mean by this is run a sql command from rails using user input like

```
Object.where("id = #{params[:id]} AND level <= #{current_user.level}")
```

will be vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: it looks like whoever downvoted me didn't get my intention. i was trying to say that this code above is vulnerable to sql injection.